# Pass command text to `bash` from `sh` without a script file?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to run a single command using `bash` in a `sh` script. There is no way to use `bash` for the script, I have to use `sh`. However, I need to run a bash-only command in `sh`.

Basically, I want something like the following:

```
bash --command_in "echo foobar"
```

Is this possible? I **don't** want to make a *second* script file just to run that one command in bash (like `bash my_script.bash`).

Answer (score 1):

Derp, it's the `-c` flag. This wasn't easy to Google, and the `--help` is prety brief.

Comment: It's in the [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash) section of the manual.